# NSString and String on Xcode Beta 6

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, swift

This code

```
        var s: String = "hello" as NSString
```

Doesn't work anymore. It fails at compiling time

```
"__TFSs26_forceBridgeFromObjectiveCU__FTPSs9AnyObject_MQ__Q_", referenced from:
```

I'm asking that because I have an object that has several optional strings, for example:

```
var title: String?
```

And when I get the NSDictionary from AFnetWorking and do something like this:

```
            obj.title = item["title"] as? String
```

It's always nil.
This code used to work just fine on Beta 5, not sure if it's a bug or something that changed. I couldn't find anything on the changelogs.

I have also tried

```
 var test: NSString = item["id"] as NSString
 obj.dealID = test
```

test var works fine, I can see the value there, but when I add the second like, it doesn't compile anymore, same error as my first example.

Comment: Try deleting your derived data for the project (it's in Window -> Organizer) and re-compiling.

Comment: @MikeS Thank you! I tried clean and build, reset the simulator, even restarted the computer and didn't work. But your suggestion worked just fine :) Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help! I ran in to the same issue myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but deleting the "DerivedData" folder alone didn't work for me.  I had to change the Build Location to "Unique" in the advanced section of Locations.  I believe that this might be because I had to quarantine xcode to get it open using the command:

```
sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app
```

But I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete your derived data in the organiser:

[image: window -> organiser]

[image: delete]